# apple touch icon not working on secure domain

Tags: client-certificates, apple-touch-icon

I wonder if anyone can help, i'm setting up apple touch icons and they all work perfectly (even on https domains) however for my companies intranet site, which uses a client certificate and secure.domain it's not working, could you please point me in the right direction?

Kind regards
Rachel

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue I had to very quickly take down the certificates, add the home screen icons and bring the certificates back up again.

Comment: It seems in my experience too that the home screen icon logic does not support specially-trusted certificates (self-signed, mismatched domain, etc.) Another option might be to host the icon on another domain with a publicly-trusted SSL/TLS certificate, and have an absolute URL to it `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://example.com/images/mysite-favicon.png">`